# How can i get the fixed position in the window?

Tags: c#, xna

How can I get the fixed position in a window? I use the 2D camera and if move the score remains behind me. I tried this but it doesn't function ofcr:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: "+ score,//here i have to put the parameters of the position , Color.Gold);
```

Comment: please try not asking the same question twice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345920/how-can-i-get-a-fixed-position-in-a-window-with-xna). Just because someone doesn't reply to your question in 30 minutes doesn't mean you can ask it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a 2D camera you need to use another `SpriteBatch` for your fixed graphics, otherwise everything you draw will slide on your screen.

```cs
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: "+ score, new Vector2(x, y), color);
spriteBatch.End();
```