# How can i get a fixed position in a window with XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I have to show my score in my game but I use 2D camera and when I move the writing "score" remains behind my player. I tried this but it doesn't function ofcr:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: "+ score, /*param of the position */, Color.Gold);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem correctly but:
Use `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` and render your text as last item.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, if you pass it a fixed Vector2 position, it should work. If not, it is not a problem related to that drawing line, but elsewhere in the code.

Perhaps an incorrect configuration of the viewport, or maybe you are 'spriteBatch.Begin'ing it incorrectly (weird transforming or the like?)

Regardless, we'll need to see some more code before we can correctly determine the problem.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a function which permits me to put that "Score" in a fixed position. It doesn't function with a fixed vector2 because when i move with my character the score remains behind and i can't see it anymore

Comment: If you're doing what I think you're doing, it's quite simple. Just make the drawing of the score the last line before the spriteBatch.End() call.